# How to make Hover Image button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make an image, which is grey scale and on hover, it gains colour, and when I click it, the button remains highlighted, I have figured the hover part out, how can I make it so it remains highlighted?

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3bMVP/20/

Comment: Welcome... please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry, i will follow the suggested guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Try using `filter`:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(0)',
           'filter': 'grayscale(0)'});
});
```

```css
button {
  
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: 1s;
  
  /* settings */
  background-image: url(http://sourcingrecruitment.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/stackoverflow.png);
  width: 512px;
  height: 512px;
  
  /* cosmetics */
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 1em;
  outline: 0;  
}

button:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bMVP/240/)

Answer (score 0):

you can write a hightlight `css` file(or a piece of code) for the tag, `class="active"`, the active is the highlight style ,when you click the image ,the event `onclick` can change the aim tag's attribute of `class`. Or use `JQuery`you can  `$("#aimNode").click(function(){$(this.toggleClass("active"))})`.